# Inversion produces unexpected existT in Coq

Tags: coq

Here is an inductive type `pc` that I am using in a mathematical theorem.

```
Inductive pc ( n : nat ) : Type :=
  | pcs : forall ( m : nat ), m < n -> pc n
  | pcm : pc n -> pc n -> pc n.
```

And another inductive type `pc_tree`, which is basically a binary tree that contains one or more `pc`s. `pcts` is a leaf node constructor that contains a single `pc`, and `pctm` is an internal node constructor that contains multiple `pc`s.

```
Inductive pc_tree : Type :=
  | pcts : forall ( n : nat ), pc n -> pc_tree
  | pctm : pc_tree -> pc_tree -> pc_tree.
```

And an inductively defined proposition `contains`. `contains n x t` means that the tree `t` contains at least one ocurrence of `x : pc n`.

```
Inductive contains ( n : nat ) ( x : pc n ) : pc_tree -> Prop :=
  | contain0 : contains n x ( pcts n x )
  | contain1 : forall ( t s : pc_tree ), contains n x t -> contains n x ( pctm t s )
  | contain2 : forall ( t s : pc_tree ), contains n x t -> contains n x ( pctm s t ).
```

Now, the problematic lemma I need to prove:

```
Lemma contains_single_eq : forall ( n : nat ) ( x y : pc n ), contains n x ( pcts n y ) -> x = y.
```

What the lemma  means is really simple: if a tree that has a single leaf node containing `y : pc n` contains some `x : pc n`, it follows that `x = y`. I thought I should be able to prove this with a simple `inversion` on `contains`. So When I wrote

```
Lemma contains_single_eq : forall ( n : nat ) ( x y : pc n ), contains n x ( pcts n y ) -> x = y.
intros n x y H. inversion H.
```

I was expecting to get `x = y` as an hypothesis in the context. Here's what I got instead:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
x : pc n
y : pc n
H : contains n x (pcts n y)
H1 : existT (fun n : nat => pc n) n x = existT (fun n : nat => pc n) n y
====================================================================== (1/1)
x = y
```

`H1` is quite different from what I expected. (I've never seen `existT` before.) All I care about is that I prove `contains_single_eq`, but I'm not sure how to use `H1` for it, or whether it is usable at all.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `{x : T & P x}` is a dependent sum like `T * P` is a nondependent sum. `@existT T P x H : {x : T & P x}` like `@pair T P x H : T * P`. `exists x : T, P x`, `{x : T | P x}`, and `{x : T & P x}` are very similar. Use the `Print ex.`, `Print sig.`, and `Print sigT.` commands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a recurring problem when doing inversion on things that involve dependent types. The equality that is generated over `existT` just means that Coq cannot invert the equality `pcts n x = pcts n y` like it would for normal types. The reason for that is that the index `n` that appears on the types of `x` and `y` cannot be generalized when typing the equality `x = y`, which is required for doing the inversion.

`existT` is the constructor for the dependent pair type, which "hides" the `nat` index and allows Coq to avoid this problem in the general case, producing a statement which is slightly similar to what you want, although not quite the same. Fortunately, for indices that have a decidable equality (such as `nat`), it is actually possible to recover the "usual" equality using theorem `inj_pair2_eq_dec` in the [standard library](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html).

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Peano_dec.

Lemma contains_single_eq : 
  forall ( n : nat ) ( x y : pc n ),
    contains n x ( pcts n y ) -> x = y.
  intros n x y H. inversion H.
  apply inj_pair2_eq_dec in H1; trivial.
  apply eq_nat_dec.
Qed.
```